# Need to get info from PHP, pass values to HTML and store values in a variable, and send variable to a page

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have been trying to get help on the following, I need to pass values after clicking a div, to a PHP form that will get information from a server, pass some values to jobseeker.php.html then store the resulting HTML in a $output variable, and pass the HTML in the output variable to a div on the page. below is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="self">
        <div class="identity" style="display: none;">1234</div>
        <div class="job_seeker_id" style="display: none;">18990</div>
        <div class="vacancy_id" style="display: none;">787</div>
        Helo
    </div>

    <div class="self">
        <div class="identity" style="display: none;">444</div>
        <div class="job_seeker_id" style="display: none;">5780</div>
        <div class="vacancy_id" style="display: none;">787</div>
        Hi there
    </div>

    <div class="self">
        <div class="identity" style="display: none;">894</div>
        <div class="job_seeker_id" style="display: none;">7800</div>
        <div class="vacancy_id" style="display: none;">787</div>
        ok
    </div>

    <div id="datahere"> Ok</div>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <script>



    $( ".self" ).on("click", function( event ) {
         var job_seeker_id = $(this).find(".job_seeker_id").text()
         var vacancy_id = $(this).find(".vacancy_id").text()
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "",
            url: 'get.php',
            data: {
                    job_seeker_id, vacancy_id 
                  },

            success: function(response){
                $("#datahere").html(response);
        }

        });

});

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The controller PHP is as follows

```
<?php

if isset($_POST['job_seeker_id']) {

$result=$jobApplicationsTable->findAllWhere('WHERE `vacancy_id`=:vacancy_id AND job_seeker_id=:job_seeker_id', [':vacancy_id' => $_POST['vacancy_id'], ':job_seeker_id'=> $_POST['job_seeker_id'] ]);

            foreach($result as $application)
                    {

                    ob_start();
                     require 'jobseeker.html.php'; 
                    $output=ob_get_clean();
                }
    }

?>
```

And the jobseeker.html.php is as follows

```
<div><h1>Job Title : <?=$application['title']?></h1></div>

<div><p>Applicant name : <?=$application['jobSeekerName']?></p></div>
```

Comment: Do I get a job if I answer the question? In the controller: Place parentheses around your `if` conditional, add 'echo $output;` as the last statement within the `if` code block. That get's you started.

Comment: Unclear what exactly you are having trouble with now. You told us what you need or want to achieve - but not what your actual _problem_ with it is now. Please go read [ask], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @misorude sorry, the output is not being placed on the page I want it to for some reason.

Comment: @RandyCasburn sorry, my mistake, but I did place parentheses around the if statement. and added the echo, this was an edit.

Comment: So what is the result of the changes I suggested. And - as **misroute** pointed out, specifically read the part about using _code snippets_. thanks.

Comment: @RandyCasburn same thing, no change. I will read on that just now.

Comment: Set `$output` to ANY STRING. and then `echo $output;` as the last line of the `if` statement. What happens?

Comment: still, nothing. this is what I have set. `if(isset($_POST['job_seeker_id'])) $output="lets go";

echo $output;`

Comment: Are you using F12 in the browser to look at the network traffic (request and response)?